# What performance hit will I get using namespace binding in Websphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

So I am working on an enterprise application and need to quantify what the hit will be moving from a jar that contains everything, to an EJB that in another EAR that is mapped using a namespace binding in Websphere.

I have tried searching for something and so far my Google-Fu has failed me.

So I pose the question, what would be my performance hit moving from a full jar to an EJB through namespace binding in Webshpere?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a local EJB interface?  If yes, then there will be minimal cost, though there are some configuration considerations.  See the "Local client views" section on the [EJB 3.0 modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cejb_emod.html) InfoCenter topic.

Is it a remote EJB interface?  If yes, you'll pay a cost to marshal/unmarshal parameters and return values between the two application class loaders.  The cost will depend on the values being marshalled.  The best advice is to do a prototype and do a performance analysis.  Any other answer is just guessing.

Comment: That is the debate we are having now.  I have been trying to find information on the difference between the two with some performance assessment from a proof of concept.  Unfortunately we are unable to do our own POC at this time.